# "She works as a courier." What is "a courier"?

Tags: interpretation

The courier is a travel guide or a delivery person or company?

Couier definition:

1. A courier is a person who is paid to take letters and parcels direct from one place to another.
2. A courier is a person employed by a travel company to look after people who are on holiday. (=rep)
3. If you courier something somewhere, you send it there by courier.

Comment: *"She is a doctor."* Who do you think she is? An ophthalmologist or a dentist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition is almost always the one referred to in this context. Otherwise, you would need additional context to provide a correct answer.

Comment: If you say "courier" it must has one meaning, English is interesting and it's really weired.

Comment: 'It must _have_ one meaning'. No, it doesn't have to. English (and, I'm sure, other languages) has words with different shades of meaning which can usually be inferred from the context.